# E4 user authentication, session, and authorization based presentation logic

Tags: eclipse, security, authorization, eclipse-rcp, e4

Context: Eclipse 4 platform RCP presentation layer (on top of a SOA backend)

1) ¿Where is the best place to store authenticated user information (HttpSession-like store, including security sensitive data)?

2) ¿Is there any advice or best practice on how to implement SWT widget/control enablement/visibility based on user permissions/profiles? (swt presentation logic being in its own bundle, agnostic of any authorization logic).

I read that in version 3.x this could be done with org.eclipse.ui.activities, there is something like that in E4?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse 4 we store most things in the model. For 'global' info like sign-ins / session data would be in the MApplication's 'persistentData' field, likely with one entry per userId.

*** but *** calling this secure is a flat lie; the model is an open book so anybody could find the info. Encryption is up to you (as is how truly secure the result is, Eclipse makes no effort to be secure internally...

As far as modifying the UI is concerned then if it's just a matter of tweaking what a person can see it's not too bad. You can find all the elements in the model and individually set their 'toBeRendered' state to false if they shouldn't be available; true if they should. This will likely work for many things but you may find that you'll have to tweak up your command's 'visibleWhen' clauses to ensure that the system doesn't make them show up again.